# How can I add a string to every value of a list, and then make a value of that string count up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to print values in a list and add strings. I want a value (colx in the string I'm adding) to count up from 0 to the last value of the list.

```
#CODE
list1 = ['dog' , 'cat', 'pig', 'cow'] 
for elem in list1:
      print(elem + ' = sheet.cell(r,colx).value')
```

Current Output:

```
dog = sheet.cell(r,colx).value
cat = sheet.cell(r,colx).value
pig = sheet.cell(r,colx).value
cow = sheet.cell(r,colx).value
```

Desired Output:

```
dog = sheet.cell(r,0).value
cat = sheet.cell(r,1).value
pig = sheet.cell(r,2).value
cow = sheet.cell(r,3).value
```

Comment: use `print(elem + ' = sheet.cell(r,{colx}).value'.format(colx=colx)) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Method 1:** using *enumerate*

```
list1 = ['dog' , 'cat', 'pig', 'cow']
for index, elem in enumerate(list1):
    print('{} = sheet.cell(r,{}).value'.format(elem, index+1)) # start counting from 1
```

> **Output:**

```
dog = sheet.cell(r,1).value
cat = sheet.cell(r,2).value
pig = sheet.cell(r,3).value
cow = sheet.cell(r,4).value
```

> **Method 2:** using a *list comprehensions* to construct a list of tuples

```
list1 = ['dog' , 'cat', 'pig', 'cow']
list1_indexes = [(k, list1[k]) for k in range(0, len(list1))]
for list_item in list1_indexes:
    print('{} = sheet.cell(r,{}).value'.format(list_item[1], list_item[0]+1))
```

> **Output:**

```
dog = sheet.cell(r,1).value
cat = sheet.cell(r,2).value
pig = sheet.cell(r,3).value
cow = sheet.cell(r,4).value
```

Answer (score 3):

For this you could print out the current index.

```
list1 = ['dog' , 'cat', 'pig', 'cow']
for idx, elem in enumerate(list1):
    print(elem + ' = sheet.cell(r,' ,idx , ').value')
```

If you need another startIndex:

```
list1 = ['dog' , 'cat', 'pig', 'cow']
startIndex = 2
for elem in list1:
    print(elem + ' = sheet.cell(r,' ,startIndex , ').value')
    startIndex = startIndex + 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Also if I wanted to start idx at 1 or a different number, how would I go about doing that? Thank you :)

Comment: For that, just add `1`to `idx`, like `print(elem + ' = sheet.cell(r,' ,idx+1 , ').value')`

Comment: you could do it like @codrelphi ... or i would prefer a own counting variable.. i edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can easly use directly this code 
list1 = ['dog' , 'cat', 'pig', 'cow']
for i, elem in enumerate(list1):
    print('{} = sheet.cell(r,{}).value'.format(elem, i+1))